# Multiple Async Calls?

Tags: javascript, async-await, axios, mobx-state-tree

I am using async/await. I am wondering how do I do multiple async calls all in parallel?

do I do

```
async method(){
   call1();
   call2();
}
```

as it seems at least from the debugger it is calling one at a time.

I am not sure if since I am using mobx state tree "flow" feature if that might be blocking `call2` from happening till `call1` is done.

```
call1: flow(function*() {
    const response = yield axios.post()
}),
```

Comment: If you don't have `await` in front of the calls, your `call1(); call2();` should make the two requests immediately (in parallel), not in serial

Comment: that's what I thought, maybe the chrome debugger just make it look like it is not, guess I will have to do some console.log to check it out

Comment: if you dont' `await`, why make the `method` async in the first place? that just confuses the issue when calling `method`

Answer (score 0):

You can try [async.js](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#parallel) parallel method. It will reduce the burden on handling different call data as well. It will do the same :

```
async.parallel([
    //different async calls you can add as many you want
    function(callback) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            callback(null, 'one');
        }, 200);
    },
    function(callback) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            callback(null, 'two');
        }, 100);
    }
],
// optional callback
function(err, results) {
    // the results array will equal ['one','two'] even though
    // the second function had a shorter timeout.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Promise.all`:

```
async method() {
   return await Promise.all([
       call1()
       call2()
   ])
}
```